# Magento : How to change the markup of category page?

Tags: php, magento, markup

I'm new to magento.

I want to customize the markup of the category section (add some divisions/links), but when I check catalog/category/view.phtml, I can  only see one function that is responsible for displaying products in the category page:

```
 <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

Tell me please where could I make changes?

Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `getProductListHtml()` is defined in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View`.

The template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` is usually loaded by calling this. Your mileage may vary, since the template can be overridden by the theme you're using.

I'd recommend to study the [Magento Design Guide](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf) and some tutorials to get a grasp.

Comment: Thanks. In which folder ? because I dont want to change the core !